# SQL Join Multiple columns in one table with one column in another table

Tags: sql-server, join

I got two tables as below

table 1 :Which got multiple columns which refers to a value in the second table.

tbale2:Lookup table where it got a row for every possible value for the columns in the above table

What I want to do is lookup the values in columns ItemID,ORDIG,CatID,MediaID in table 1 from ValueID in table2 and return ValueName

so at the end my result should look like

```
ItemID   OrgID  CatID    MediaID
i859049  Singapore  Full  0001edf
```

Comment: Could you please post your tables layout?

Comment: Sorry I uploaded a pic but not sure what happened to it 

table1:

ItemID OrgID CatID MediID 
18959  1        2        3
18960  4 5        6

Table2:

ValueID valueNAme
1 Singapore
2 Full
3 001edf
4 UK
5 Partial
6 002efg
7       London
8       Empty
9       00000


Output i need


ItemID OrgID  CatID  MediID 
18959  Singapore        Full            001edf
18960  UK  Partial         002efg

Comment: pics are not the best way to post the table structure. Could you please just paste `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to join to the lookup table once for each value you need, but should likely need to use a `LEFT` instead of `INNER` join since the values may be null.

```
SELECT 
    T1.ItemId,
    Items.ValueName AS ItemName,
    T1.OrgID,
    Orgs.ValueName AS OrgName,
    T1.CatID,
    Cats.ValueName AS CatName,
    T1.MediaID,
    Media.ValueName AS MediaName
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 Items
        ON T1.ItemId = Items.ValueID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 Orgs
        ON T1.OrgId = Orgs.ValueID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 Cats
        ON T1.CatId = Cats.ValueID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 Media
        ON T1.MediaId = Media.ValueID
```

Comment: That works !! thanks very much. Now if I want to Join Item ID to another table do I 1st join itemid and continue with this statement?